# What reasons are there to using cooked user defined literals over free functions?

Tags: c++11

Compared to a free function, I don't see much benefit to using a cooked user defined literal. The latter may be nicer in terms of syntax, but I see some issues:

- To avoid collisions between commonly named literals you may need to use specific scopes with `using namespace` directives since you can't qualify the literals
- You need to use the widest argument for integers and floating point types

The first point can be especially annoying as it requires you to structure your code a certain way if you have collisions. It also means that it may be a bad idea to use literals in header files. For example, doing the following would require you to bring in a namespace:

```
// Thing.h
using namespace unit_literals;

class Thing {
    Property<Dimension> length{5.0_cm};
};
```

With a free function you can qualify when there's a collision.

```
// Thing.h

class Thing {
    Property<Dimension> length{units::cm(5.0)};
};
```

Using free functions also lets you avoid writing user defined literals for both floating point and integer types:

```
Dimension cm(float in) { return ...; }

Property<Dimension> length{units::cm(5.0)}; // ok
Property<Dimension> length{units::cm(5)}; // ok
```

What reasons are there to prefer using cooked user defined literals over free functions?

Comment: Note that `using namespace <whatever>;` is limited to the scope it's used in, so using it in a header might not be too bad if you locate it well. As to the rest of your question, I have no help for you... :)